# Checking for multiple child constraint violations in Hibernate/JPA

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

TL;DR:  Is it possible to perform nested transactions in Hibernate that use SavePoints to rollback to specific states?

So I am attempting to persist a parent entity with a OneToMany mapping to child entities.  This is working fine.

During this persistence, I would like to catch and log ALL constraint violations that occur. Currently, the FIRST entity (child or parent) to have a constraint violation throws a ConstraintViolationException and rolls back the transaction.  I would like for the transaction to still be rolled back, but somehow collect ALL of the constraint violations that would occur.

Here is a brief outline of my entities:

ParentEntity.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "PARENT", schema = "SOMESCHEMA")
public class ParentEntity {

    private static final ID_COLUMN = "ID_COLUMN";

    @Id
    @Column(name = ID_COLUMN)
    private Long id;    

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = ID_COLUMN, referencedColumnName = ID_COLUMN)
    private List<childEntity> children;
}
```

ChildEntity.java

```java
@Entity
@Table(name = "CHILD", schema = "SOMESCHEMA")
public class ChildEntity {

    public ChildEntity(String input) {
        this.validationString = input;
    } 

    @Id
    @Column(name = ParentEntity.ID_COLUMN)
    private Long id;    

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = ParentEntity.ID_COLUMN, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private ParentEntity parent;

    // The field under validation (should be less than 25 char's long)
    @Column(name = "VALIDATE_ME")
    private String validationString;
}
```

Example run:

```java
public void someMethod() {
    ParentEntity parent = new ParentEntity();

    parent.addChild(new Child("good input 1"));
    parent.addChild(new Child("bad input 1             break here"));
    parent.addChild(new Child("bad input 2             break here"));
    parent.addChild(new Child("good input 2"));

    dataAccessObject.persist(parent);
}
```

Results:

I see the transaction rolled back and the `ConstraintViolationException` only contains information for the first bad child.

Desired Results:

I see the transaction rolled back and the `ConstraintViolationException` show information for all the bad children regardless of how many children were bad.  (Also, if the parent has a constraint violation, I would still like to check the child constraints)

Is this possible?

Comment: no.. that isn't how sql database work.

Comment: @M.Deinum That isn't exactly helpful.  Also this is a question for Hibernate/JPA not SQL.  The database can support insertions/deletions/etc.

Comment: No JPA is in the end SQL and SQL is designed to fail as soon as a constraint fails, it doesn't evaluate after that. So based on the underlying technology it isn't possible. Unless you use something like validation and validate before hand using JSR-303 for instance.

Comment: I understand that.  Maybe you just didn't read my question in its entirety.  I understand SQL will rollback a transaction on the first constraint violation that occurs.   That's why I proposed nested transactions.  I know that a rollback should be unrecoverable and I was fine with that, I simply wanted to force a continuance to catch ALL of the possible constraint violations.

And looking back, it IS possible to do what I wanted, it just had undesirable side-effects and required more implementation than was warranted.

In the end, I did use JSR-303 based validation.

Comment: Nested transactions won't work nor are a solution. If something happens after something is committed you basically end up with your database being in the wrong state. Next to that how many nested transactions are you going to use? 1, 2 or 1 for each possible constraint that might fail? Which can (and will) lead to performance issues due to database and/or table locks.

Comment: The undesirable side-effect I mentioned in my previous comment was the database being in an improper state.  The performance issues were something else to consider as well.

Thank you for your information.  I think we are in agreement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to accomplish my end result, although it was through means I did not expect.

In order to accomplish my goal, I would need to use nested transactions and SavePoints.  At the end of the day, that implementation would still produce invalid data in my database, because during the time it takes to find an error in a child, some of the other children may have already been persisted and a consumer of my database would be unaware that the parent and all it's children were about to be deleted due to one or more bad entities (parents or children).

My solution:

I implemented a validator to validate all of the parents and children before going to persist them.  The drawback to this method is that I have to annotate constraints on my entity fields, but double validation is never a bad thing.

The answer to my original question:

This is impossible to due with my version of Hibernate, unless I implemented custom SavePoint functionality to support nested transactions.

Comment: @MDeinum pointed out a few issues with my question, which are resolved by approaching the problem from this new viewpoint.

Nested transactions were simply a bad solution to the problem at hand.  Validation was much simpler, more performant, and left no possibility for side-effects in the data.

Answer (score 0):

ConstraintViolationException is a HibernateException and all Hibernate exceptions are not recoverable. So if one exception is thrown, you cannot rely on the existing session state to continue processing reliably.

So this is not possible or recommended.

Comment: Thank you for your input.  I have rethought my approach.  Nested transactions as a solution for this problem would be a bad idea.